# Magento 2.1 Display Product details,image in Success page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, order-success-page

I want to display Product details in which if it is configurable with options, image in Success page.

Comment: Please post what you have already tried to accomplish this.

Comment: i want to display product details of what we ordered in success page